# How to remove UINavigationBar label.text from second UIView Controller which is coming in first View controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have one label which I am showing on UINavigationBar using addSubView Property and I am getting like:[image]

But when I am going to secondView Controller, it is looking like:[image]

It appears on Back Button of Second Controller. So how to remove "Status" Label from second UI.

Thank You.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `addSubView`. Did you read it's official class reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first View controller -

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    //Add Label on UINavigationBar
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:navLabel];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    // Remove label from UINavigationBar
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [navLabel removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't add subviews to the navigation bar. It's not made for that.
I recommend you to read the [iOS human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Bars.html) and to use a [UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to properly add controls to the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

You should tag your subview and search for it among subviews of navigation bar in your second view controller and then `[subview removeFromSuperview]`.

You shouldn't add subviews to your navigation bar, you can use navigation items to achieve that kind of stuff. You can init a `UIBarButtonItem` with `initWithCustomView:` which has that label in it.

Comment: But we can not use addSubview property by navigates Item.

Comment: Every view controller has its own navigation items, when you create an UIBarButtonItem with custom view (like the label in your question) and add it to navigation items array of appropriate view controller then the view controller prints the label onto navigation bar, it will disappear after you push another view controller.